# combobox is not populating as combobox but like text

Tags: php, mysql, combobox

i am trying to get the data from mysql in combobox based on another combobox. it is getting the data according to the selection.
but the problem is i and not getting the resulted data in a proper manner.

[image]

and another issue is i want the data to be shown on page load also not only when i change the selection.
When the page loads it doesnt show anything for Test Names But after changing it shows.
[image]

please help.  thanks alot

.js Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$(".country").change(function()
{
var id=$(this).val();
var dataString = 'id='+ id;

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax_city.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$(".city").html(html);
} 
});

});
});
</script>
```

index.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="assets-global/js/getdata/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select name="country" class="country" style="width:625px;">
        <?php
        include('con_pick.php');
        $query = "select * from main_cats";
        $results = mysql_query($query);

        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
        {
        $idc    =   $rows['id'];
        $q_selected_cat = mysql_query("SELECT mcat_id FROM questions WHERE mcat_id='$mcat_id' ");   
        $category = mysql_fetch_assoc($q_selected_cat);
        $selected_category  = $category['mcat_id'];
        if($idc == $selected_category){
        ?>
            <option selected value="<?php echo $rows['id'];?>"><?php echo $rows['unique_name'];?></option>
        <?php }else{ ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rows['id'];?>"><?php echo $rows['unique_name'];?></option>
        <?php } } ?>
</select>   
<select name="city" class="city"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax_city.php:

```
<?php
include('con_pick.php');
if($_POST['id'])
{
$id=$_POST['id'];


$q_all_categories1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tests where mcat_id=$id");
while ($all_categories1 = mysql_fetch_array($q_all_categories1))
{
    $category_id1 = $all_categories1['id'];
    $categories_name1 = $all_categories1['unique_name'];

    $q_selected_cat1 = mysql_query("SELECT test_id FROM questions WHERE test_id=$test_id and id =$cats_id ");

    $selected1 = "";
    while ($category1 = mysql_fetch_array($q_selected_cat1))
    {
        $selected_category1 = $category1['test_id'];
        if($category_id1 == $selected_category1){$selected1 = "selected";}
    }
    print   "<option class='' ".$selected1." value='".$category_id1."'>".$categories_name1."</option>";
    $selected1 = "";
}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue:
Your screenshot (talks about categories) does not seem to match the code (talkes about countries).
It seems you are missing 'city' from index.php, so add that:

```
<select name="city" class="city"></select>
```

Also I would use data in your ajax call:

```
data: { 
  'id': id
},
```

If things do not work as expected, try to console.log(your result). It could be the php script gives a warning or times out?

Your second issue:
When the page has loaded, you can call the change() event - it is as if the user has caused the changed. From here: https://api.jquery.com/change/

> To trigger the event manually, apply .change() without arguments

Also:
Your code for ajax_city.php does not validate its input but sends what it gets straight to the SQL server. Imagine $_POST['id'] is this text: "0; DROP TABLE tests;" - you will lose your table. A simple (int) before $_POST['id'] would prevent that (but read up on SQL injection).

Comment: sorry by mistake did not pasted the other select of city edited now.
would you please be so kind if you edit my code and re-post it????

Comment: Well @Herbert Van-Vliet thanks for your kind reply. but i cannot figure it out when i tried to use this with mysql it is not getting the data. please see my code and if you can configure everything withmy code and make it working if possible... thanks alot in advance